Error: Cannot find module 'index'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs using nodejs
I have been struggling with this error for the past few days and I tried all the combinations using hotreload and zip file, lambda function is created but when triggered it isn't pointing to the location that's been provided in hotreload. It would be really great if anyone here can help me with this issue. This is using nodejs.
Here is the error:

[   asgi_gw_0] l.s.l.i.executor_endpoint  : Execution environment
startup failed:
{"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot
find module 'index'\nRequire stack:\n-
/var/runtime/index.mjs","trace":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error:
Cannot find module 'index'","Require stack:","-
/var/runtime/index.mjs","    at _loadUserApp
(file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)","    at async
UserFunction.js.module.exports.load
(file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)","    at async start
(file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)","    at async
file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"]}

Docker compose
version: "3.0"

networks:
  test:

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:3.4.0
    networks:
      - test
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sns,sqs,kms,events,lambda,s3,iam
      - LOCALSTACK_HOST=localstack
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=test
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=test
      - AWS_REGION=eu-west-2
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
      - DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
      - SKIP_SSL_CERT_DOWNLOAD=1
      - LOCALSTACK_KMS_BACKEND=moto
      - LAMBDA_RUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT_TIMEOUT=2000
      - LAMBDA_KEEPALIVE_MS=6000000
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker-reuse
      - DEBUG=0
      - UPDATE_REQUEST_QUEUE_URL=http://localstack:4566/000000000000/test_update_request_queue.fifo
      - UPDATE_REQUEST_SNS_TOPIC_ARN=arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:000000000000:test_update_request_queue.fifo
      - MESSAGE_GROUPS=2
    volumes:
      - ./test/integration/localstackinit.d/init:/etc/localstack/init/boot.d/
      - ./test/integration/localstackinit.d/ready/:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/
      - ./sd_refresh_docs.zip://home/aws/functions/sd_refresh_docs.zip
      - ./:/usr/lambda/
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/_localstack/health" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
    expose:
      - 4566
      - 4575
      - 9915
    ports:
      - 4566:4566
      - 4575:4575
      - 9915:9915
      - 4571:4572
      - 8090:8080


awslocal cmd
awslocal  lambda create-function \
  --code S3Bucket='hot-reload',S3Key='/usr/lambda' \
  --function-name sd-refresh-docs-function \
  --handler app/index.handler \
  --role "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/DummyRole" \
  --runtime nodejs20.x \
  --environment "Variables={LOG_LEVEL=debug,UPDATE_REQUEST_QUEUE_URL=${UPDATE_REQUEST_QUEUE_URL},MESSAGE_GROUPS=2}"
log "Created Lambda function"


package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "7.24.5",
    "@dwp/ui-core": "2.0.0-release.897211608",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "5.1.3",
    "prettier": "3.2.5",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1618.0",
    "winston": "3.13.0"
  },

FOLDER STRUCTURE

I have tried creating a lambda using localstack, aws lambda is created fine but fails when triggered with the above error. I have tried with both zip file and hotreload, example provided is with hotreload.
